# How do I remove a test step using groovy in soapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

Can someone please advise how to remove a test step in SoapUI using groovy?

In my project, I have a REST test request that gets generated and executed on the fly. Once the request has been submitted, I would like to automatically remove this step using groovy script.

I tried something like:

```
testRunner.testCase.removeTestStep( "Trigger_REST_Request" );
```

But this returns error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.removeTestStep()
 is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Trigger_REST_Request]
 Possible solutions:     
    removeTestStep(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestStep), 
    moveTestStep(int, int) groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
```

Thanks!

Well that worked....sort of. When I added the suggested two lines, I can see that the test step is removed, however, I'm also receiving a NullPointerException now. As a result the test suite exits after NPE is returned.  This is the NPE error I get:

```
Wed Sep 21 09:27:11 EST 2016:ERROR:java.lang.NullPointerException
   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.eviware.soapui.model.support.ModelSupport.dependsOn(ModelSupport.java:196)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.actions.ShowMessageExchangeAction$MessageExchangeDesktopPanel.dependsOn(ShowMessageExchangeAction.java:203)
at com.eviware.soapui.ui.desktop.AbstractSoapUIDesktop.closeDependantPanels(AbstractSoapUIDesktop.java:101)
at com.eviware.soapui.ui.desktop.AbstractSoapUIDesktop$InternalTestSuiteListener.testStepRemoved(AbstractSoapUIDesktop.java:190)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuite.fireTestStepRemoved(WsdlTestSuite.java:277)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.removeTestStep(WsdlTestCase.java:577)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase$removeTestStep.call(Unknown Source)
at Script9.run(Script9.groovy:19)
at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:92)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:211)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:47)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:138)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:46)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:129)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Have you tried either of the options given to you in the exception text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to remove the test step, use the following code:

```
def tc = testRunner.testCase
def tbr = tc.getTestStepByName('ToBeRemoved')
if (tbr != null) { 
  tc.removeTestStep(tbr)
}
```

The script handles also the case when the ToBeRemoved test step does not exist.

Comment: When I added the suggested two lines, I'm now receiving a NPE exception. See update in original question above. Any ideas as to why I'm getting this error?